# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: d3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, jasmine

Hello all I am trying to do some jasmine/karma testing on a d3 application however I cannot get past this error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: d3...

```
at getSvg (C:/Users/test/Desktop/bob/angular-force-directed-graph/src/app/d3mapping.spec.js:9)
            at C:/Users/test/Desktop/bob/angular-force-directed-graph/src/app/d3mapping.spec.js:9
        ReferenceError: Can't find variable: d3
```

I know it has something to do with d3 being undefined until window.load but I am not sure how to properly define d3 and the methods it uses.

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Thu Oct 29 2015 14:09:24 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({

        // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
        basePath: 'app',


        // frameworks to use
        // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],


        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
            'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
            'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
            'bower_components/d3/d3.js',

            'home/*.js',
            'common/*.js',
            'home/home.module.js',


            'app.js',
            '**/*.module.js',
            '**/*.controller.js',
            '**/*.service.js',

            '**/*.directive.js',
            '**/*.routes.js',

            '**/*.spec.js'
        ],


        // list of files to exclude
        exclude: [
            'bower_components/**/!(angular*|angular-mocks|angular-route*).js'
        ],


        // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
        // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
        preprocessors: {
            '!(bower_components)/**/!(*spec).js': 'coverage',
            '*.js': 'coverage'
        },

        // test results reporter to use
        // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
        // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
        reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],

        coverageReporter: {
            dir: '../coverage/',
            subdir: 'report'
        },

        captureTimeout: 30000,

        // web server port
        port: 9876,


        // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
        colors: true,


        // level of logging
        // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


        // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
        autoWatch: false,


        // start these browsers
        // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
        browsers: ['Chrome', 'Firefox', 'IE', 'PhantomJS'],


        // Continuous Integration mode
        // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
        singleRun: true,

        // Concurrency level
        // how many browser should be started simultanous
        concurrency: Infinity
    })
};
```

[image]

Comment: how does your karma.config look like?

Comment: added to the question

Answer (score 1):

add d3 to your karma.conf.js files

if your project structure looks like this

```
|--app
| |--app.js
| |--...
|
|--test
| |--karma.conf.js
|
|--bower_components
```

you have to set the basePath to '../' because the karma.conf.js file lies inside the test folder but you want to address the files via 'app/app.js' or 'bower_components/...'

```
config.set({
    basePath: '../' // dont forget the right basePath!
    files:[
        'path/to/d3'
    ],
    ...
})
```

Comment: this has been completed

Comment: what is the basePath supposed to be pointing too?   basePath: '../Myapp',

Comment: depends on the location of the karma.conf.js file, i'll edit my answer

Comment: so I tried messing around with the basepath and it went from 3/3 errors to PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.002 secs / 0 secs)
it means the basepath was right

Comment: uploaded to original

Comment: I'm not sure if your exclutions are right. Try it without the wildcards.